# How can I address `MASS::polr` creating zeros through log transformation and not converging

Tags: r, model, statistics, regression, ordinal

I'm trying to use `MASS:polr` to create an ordinal regression model, but when I run the code below it returns `Error in svd(X): infinite or missing values in 'x'`. After double-checking there aren't any missing or infinite values, I did some digging and found that a log transformation is part of this process, so I ran `log(as.numeric$data$Value))` and saw that the `4`'s in my original data are being returned as zeros.

Does anyone know how to work with this? and make the model converge? I've been able to get it to work with seemingly similar data and model construction but no luck here.

Thanks legends!

```
    library(MASS)

data <- tibble::tribble(
          ~Group,  ~Time, ~Value,
  "Intervention",  "Pre",      5,
  "Intervention",  "Pre",      5,
  "Intervention",  "Pre",      5,
  "Intervention",  "Pre",      5,
  "Intervention",  "Pre",      5,
  "Intervention",  "Pre",      4,
       "Control",  "Pre",      5,
       "Control",  "Pre",      6,
       "Control",  "Pre",      5,
       "Control",  "Pre",      5,
       "Control",  "Pre",      5,
       "Control",  "Pre",      5,
       "Control",  "Pre",      4,
       "Control",  "Pre",      4,
  "Intervention", "Post",      8,
  "Intervention", "Post",      8,
  "Intervention", "Post",      8,
  "Intervention", "Post",      8,
  "Intervention", "Post",      8,
  "Intervention", "Post",      9,
       "Control", "Post",      8,
       "Control", "Post",      8,
       "Control", "Post",      7,
       "Control", "Post",      8,
       "Control", "Post",      7,
       "Control", "Post",      8,
       "Control", "Post",      8,
       "Control", "Post",      7
  )


model <- polr(factor(Value) ~ Group + Time + Group*Time, 
                 data = data,
                 Hess = TRUE)
```

Comment: `Value` is a factor right ? Factors are, behind the stage, numeric values. 4 must be level  0 for `R`. Is your factor ordered ? `log(as.numeric(as.character(data$Value)))` should return you 4, not 0.

Comment: polr::MASS doc `The response should be a factor (preferably an ordered factor), which will be interpreted as an ordinal response, with levels ordered as in the factor. `

Comment: Yes, `Value` is a factor. When I run `levels(data$Value)`, I get `[1] "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9"`. I've just run your `log(as.numeric(as.character(data$Value)))` and it doesn't return any zeros. It's now a matter of getting it to play with `MASS::polr`. Do you think I need to transform my `Value` metric to a different type before running it through `polr`?

Comment: I would first try to provide an **ordered** factor. Maybe do that explicitly using `data$Value <- factor(as.character(data$Value), levels = c("4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), ordered = TRUE)`. If it does not work, in that case I would use another variable type. Let me know if it helps (like that I put this as an answer that could help other users)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I believe the factor is already considered 'ordered', as running your code doesn't change the output of `levels(data$Value)`, and the model summary still returns the same error in the original question. The answer seems to be somewhere in the difference between `log(as.numeric(data$Value))` which produces zeros, and `log(as.numeric(as.character(data$Value)))` which does not.

Comment: Ok in that case, maybe change your datatype to `character` before trying to run `polr`

Comment: Hmm seems `MASS::polr` won't accept any response variable other than a factor. Must be more to it than I thought. The strange thing is that I successfully ran `polr` with a different response variable that was a factor, same # of observations, 5 responses (instead of 6 in this question). I don't understand why that one would work and this one doesn't.

Comment: Ok, in that case I hope someone more specialist than me with `MASS` package will give you some clues.